# Speed of light and wavelength

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction

Does the speed of Electromagnetic wave depend on its wave length? For vacuum I'm aware that it's a constant $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_o\epsilon_o}}$. Similarly can we say speed of light in any medium is a constant and is equal to $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$.

If yes, then refraction shouldn't be possible right ?

If no, then does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$ have any significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\epsilon$  - and, to a lesser extent $\mu$ - depends on the frequency of the light. The atoms of the medium have a particular excitation frequency, or frequencies, and the polarisability of the atom rises as the EM frequency rises to a peak when it equals the atomic excitation frequency, and then falls off. It's standard forced SHM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force .
So different frequencies, and hence different wavelengths, have different velocities.

Comment: does $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$ have any significance?

Comment: @Vilvanesh, yes it's the speed of light in that medium. If there was no dependence on wavelength, then a prism wouldn't separate white light into its color components.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light in a material does in general depend on wavelength, and there's no better demonstration of this fact than a prism. Since the index of refraction is

$$n = \frac{c}{v}$$

(where $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum and $v$ is the speed in the medium) and the angle of refraction depends on $n$, the fact that light splits into colors when going through a prism tells us that $n$ depends on the wavelength, and then so does $v$.

Comment: does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$ have any significance?